# Android: SimpleFTP - Empty file

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I am writing an application and want to programmatically upload a html file to my ftp server. The problem is that I'm transmitting an empty file to the server. Why? I don't know, that's why I'm asking.

the App class is a class i'm storing objects I can't pass using INTENT.

Where is the mistake, am I creating the InputStream incorrectly? Is it the incorrect Character set?

I hope I haven't missed any code, If I have, please tell me!

### ***The code:***

**SimpleFTP:** http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/

**InputStream creator:**

```
public void packHTML(List<Question> questions){
    try {
        String fileName = name + new Random().nextInt() + ".html";

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/london_HTML");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir, fileName);

        FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream(file);

        fw.write("<html>\n".getBytes());
        fw.write(("<head><title>" +name +"'s antwoorden</title></head>\n").getBytes());
        fw.write("<body>\n".getBytes());
        fw.write(("<h1>" +name +"'s antwoorden</h1><br>\n").getBytes());
        for(int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++){
            fw.write(questions.get(i).getAsHtml().getBytes());
        }
        fw.write("</body>\n".getBytes());
        fw.write("</html>".getBytes());
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        b.append("<html>\n");
        b.append("<head><title>" +name +"'s antwoorden</title></head>\n");
        b.append("<body>\n");
        b.append("<h1>" +name +"'s antwoorden</h1><br>\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++){
            b.append(questions.get(i).getAsHtml());
        }
        b.append("</body>\n");
        b.append("</html>\n");

        //StringReader r = new StringReader(b.toString());

        App.in = new ByteArrayInputStream(b.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

        file.setReadable(true, false);
        App.file = file;
        System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfirmActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("localAddress", this.getFilesDir().getPath() +"/" +fileName);
        intent.putExtra("webAddress", "http://yteditors.tk/luploads/" +fileName);
        intent.putExtra("fileName", fileName);
        intent.putExtra("name", name);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Error with file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Transmitter:**

```
public void sendFtp() throws Exception{
    SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();
    ftp.connect("IP", PORT, "UN", "PASS");
    ftp.bin();
    ftp.stor(App.in, getIntent().getExtras().getString("fileName"));
    ftp.disconnect();
}
```

EDIT:

I MIGHT have found the problem: on command "STOR" The server replies "331" wich means it still needs password authentication. Anyway, thank you for helping!

EDIT:

NOT the problem, still empty file.. :(

Comment: `objects I can't pass using INTENT` why can't you pass the file path using intent and opening a fileinputstream in sendFtp?

Comment: @njzk2 I tried that but it was throwing FileNotFoundException, so I tried this.